# Format date on insert in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I am trying to insert date in table in format DD.MM.YYYY, How do I do it?
Here is the code what I am trying, but there are some errors in it:

```
insert into nol_art_izm([ART_ID], [DAT])
    select distinct
        a.ID, DATE_FORMAT({fn now()},'%d.%c.%Y')
    from
        openxml(@hDoc, '/art_komp/nol_art') with #artTMPL xd
        join nol_art a on xd.cd = a.cd
```

Edit
**Answer**
Solved it by myself. I am inserting in DAT column with now(), but I am formatting my view column like I needed.

Comment: @cctan Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure INSERT_UPDATE_ART_KOMP_XML, Line 507
'DATE_FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: that's strange. What is your mysql version?

Comment: That doesn't look like a MySQL error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work:

```
DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%d.%m.%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

edit:

Mysql has functions to change format. I found:

```
str_to_date('".$mydate."', '%d-%c-%Y')
```